# Convert email attachment to base64

Tags: f#, stream, base64, arrays, c#-to-f#

I want to take an attachment from an email and convert it to a base64 string so that I can store it as JSON.

In C#, I would get the attachment as a `System.IO.Stream`, read it into a byte array, and then use `Convert.ToBase64String`.

In F# though, I'm not sure how to this (I'm a beginner) and it feels like there is probably a much more functional way of doing things...?

Comment: Email attachments are usually already encoded in base64 inside of the message. Refer to http://www.azure.org.ua/en/articles/10-Compose_email_with_attachment_from_command_line_shell_script.html

Comment: So I can check if the attachment is base64 and use it as is if it is, that's cool, but I still need help on what to do if it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# combines functional style with object-oriented style, so that you can easily call .NET libraries from F#. Sometimes there are F#-specific libraries that give you a more functional style for some tasks (like list processing), but I don't think there is anything like that for base64 encoding and streams.

So, given a stream, you can read it into a buffer and then convert to base64 using .NET types as follows:

```
open System
open System.IO

let stream = // Some stream, for example: new MemoryStream([| 1uy; 2uy; 3uy; 4uy |])
let buffer = Array.zeroCreate (int stream.Length)
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
```

Comment: That's great thanks. Array.zeroCreate was what I was looking for. Also I think I have some prejudice against using an OO style in F# when in fact I should be embracing it.